# Oracle - Trigger is invalid and failed to re-validation

Tags: oracle

I get error "Trigger is invalid and failed to re-validation" about my trigger when update table. Here is my trigger:

```
create or replace trigger t_backup_sal before update on employees
for each row 
begin
    merge into sal_backup sb using employees e
    on (sb.emp_id = e.emp_id) 
    when matched then 
      update set sb.emp_id = e.emp_id,
                 sb.salary = e.salary,
                 sb.time_change = sysdate
    when not matched then 
      insert (sb.emp_id, sb.salary, sb.time_change)
      values (e.emp_id, e.salary, sysdate)
end;
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: `select * from user_errors` after trigger creation. But this trigger will not work because access to the same table is prohibited in `for each row` trigger causing `ORA-04091`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error you got means that you performed action (updated `employees` table) which caused trigger to fire. However, as trigger is invalid, Oracle can't execute its code and informed you about it.

Query `user_errors` for more info.

---

Sample tables:

```
SQL> create table employees
  2  (emp_id number, salary number);

Table created.

SQL> create table sal_backup
  2  (emp_id number, salary number, time_change date);

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t_backup_sal before update on employees
  2  for each row
  3  begin
  4      merge into sal_backup sb using employees e
  5      on (sb.emp_id = e.emp_id)
  6      when matched then
  7        update set sb.emp_id = e.emp_id,
  8                   sb.salary = e.salary,
  9                   sb.time_change = sysdate
 10      when not matched then
 11        insert (sb.emp_id, sb.salary, sb.time_change)
 12        values (e.emp_id, e.salary, sysdate)
 13  end;
 14  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

What's wrong?

```
SQL> select line, position, text
  2  from user_Errors
  3  where name = 'T_BACKUP_SAL';

      LINE   POSITION TEXT
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        10         44 PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
         2          5 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
        11          4 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of
                      the following:

                         ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
                         null pragma raise return select update while with
                         <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
                         <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
                         insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
                         merge pipe purge


SQL>
```

Basically, it says that you're missing a semi-colon which terminates the `merge` statement:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t_backup_sal before update on employees
  2  for each row
  3  begin
  4      merge into sal_backup sb using employees e
  5      on (sb.emp_id = e.emp_id)
  6      when matched then
  7        update set sb.emp_id = e.emp_id,
  8                   sb.salary = e.salary,
  9                   sb.time_change = sysdate
 10      when not matched then
 11        insert (sb.emp_id, sb.salary, sb.time_change)
 12        values (e.emp_id, e.salary, sysdate);    --> here
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

---

So, does it work now?

```
SQL> insert into employees (emp_id, salary) values (1, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> update employees set salary = 200;
update employees set salary = 200
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-38104: Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated: "SB"."EMP_ID"
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.T_BACKUP_SAL", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.T_BACKUP_SAL'


SQL>
```

Well, that's another error.

Back to square 1:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t_backup_sal before update on employees
  2  for each row
  3  begin
  4      merge into sal_backup sb using employees e
  5      on (sb.emp_id = e.emp_id)              -- sb.emp_id is used here
  6      when matched then
  7        update set -- sb.emp_id = e.emp_id,  -- you can't update that column, and it
  8                   sb.salary = e.salary,     -- doesn't make sense to do so
  9                   sb.time_change = sysdate
 10      when not matched then
 11        insert (sb.emp_id, sb.salary, sb.time_change)
 12        values (e.emp_id, e.salary, sysdate);
 13  end;
 14  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Repeat:

```
SQL> update employees set salary = 200;
update employees set salary = 200
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04091: table SCOTT.EMPLOYEES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.T_BACKUP_SAL", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.T_BACKUP_SAL'


SQL>
```

Another error! What does that mean? It means that you can't select from a table which is just being modified. Use pseudorecord, instead (identified by `:new.` and `:old.` for ID (which is always the same - I hope you aren't modifying employee's ID!?) and salary (as you probably want to backup previous value).

You know the drill: back to square 1:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger t_backup_sal before update on employees
  2  for each row
  3  begin
  4      merge into sal_backup sb
  5        using (select :new.emp_id as emp_id,
  6                      :new.salary as salary
  7               from dual) e
  8      on (sb.emp_id = e.emp_id)
  9      when matched then
 10        update set sb.salary = e.salary,
 11                   sb.time_change = sysdate
 12      when not matched then
 13        insert (sb.emp_id, sb.salary, sb.time_change)
 14        values (e.emp_id, e.salary, sysdate);
 15  end;
 16  /

Trigger created.
```

Does it work now? Yes!

```
SQL> update employees set salary = 200;

1 row updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from sal_backup;

    EMP_ID     SALARY TIME_CHA
---------- ---------- --------
         1        100 09.08.23

SQL>
```